# Browser's auto request detection with X-Purpose

Tags: web-crawlers, browsers, http-headers

3 to 4 months ago, I found out that safari/chrome/firefox all have feature that automatically send request with `X-Purpose` header (with `preview` value for Safari) to get live thumbnail or top sites thumbnail (I don't really remember exactly) and I made my tracker to not count that request as a request from a real visitor.

Today, I recognize so many requests that have "Preview" header with "X-Purpose" value which is the opposite of what I described above. Do those requests have the same purpose as those I described above? Where should I read to keep track of those auto requests like that so I can make necessary changes to my tracker?